# Magento Cronjob at specific time does not work

Tags: magento, cron, magento-1.5, cron-task

I created a Magento Extension with a configurable cronjob. The path and time is saved in the core_config_data.

If I change the time to a minute interval directly in the database the cronjob works. For example */5 * * * * works great for every 5 minutes.

But if I use specific times like 20 10 * * * for every day 10:20, the cronjob doesn't work and won't be listet in the cron_schedule table.

Any idea what may be the problem?

Thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Dgroup_Emailexport>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Dgroup_Emailexport>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Emailexport>
                <class>Dgroup_Emailexport_Model</class>
            </Emailexport>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <Emailexport>
                <class>Dgroup_Emailexport_Helper</class>
            </Emailexport>
        </helpers>
    </global>

    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <dgroupemailexportcron>
                <run>
                    <model>Emailexport/exportMail::sendExport</model>
                </run>
            </dgroupemailexportcron>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>

    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <dgroup>
                                            <title>dgroup - All</title>
                                        </dgroup>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
    <default>
        <dgroup>
            <dgroup_group>               
                <dgroup_domain>example.org</dgroup_domain>        
            </dgroup_group>       
        </dgroup>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: put config.xml file code

Comment: added the config.xml. The tutorial for the configurable cronjob I used is here: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento-configurable-cron/

I also tried to run the cron every hour. It works fine. Just specific times won't work.

Comment: Magento does not generate all tasks to `cron_schedule` table. It only generate tasks that will be run in next short time (By default, it generate tasks for next 15 minutes). So, may be your schedule time is too far in future.

Comment: I thought about this by myself, but I also tried specific times which are only 5 minutes ahead : /

Answer (score 0):

I have modify the config.xml.check this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Dgroup_Emailexport>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Dgroup_Emailexport>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <emailexport>
                <class>Dgroup_Emailexport_Model</class>
            </emailexport>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <emailexport>
                <class>Dgroup_Emailexport_Helper</class>
            </emailexport>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <my_cron>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>20 10 * * * </cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>emailexport/emailexport::sendExport</model>
                </run>
            </my_cron>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>

    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <dgroup>
                                            <title>dgroup - All</title>
                                        </dgroup>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
    <default>
        <dgroup>
            <dgroup_group>               
                <dgroup_domain>example.org</dgroup_domain>        
            </dgroup_group>       
        </dgroup>
    </default>
</config>
```

File location  for sendExport is  `Dgroup>Emailexport>Model>Emailexport.php`
and

Comment: I cant set the cron_expor manually in the config. The point is that I want a cronjob which is configurable in the admin panel.

There shouldn't be a cron_expor node in the xml because the cron.php has to collect the information from the core_config_data. 

Otherwise it's not possible to create a configurable cronjob.

The cron.php does collect the time from the core_config_data. It works great if I use times like every minute, every hour and so on. But specifict times don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Depends when you test it.By default magento schedule the tasks only 20 minutes ahead. Increasing this value could help you. [image]